# How can I keep the browser pinch to zoom and use the hammer.js pinch events?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, pinchzoom

Here is my code... just a simple test as I have never used hammer.js before:

```
var hammerTime = new Hammer($('#hammerTarget').get(0));

hammerTime.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinch'})); // Add pinch gesture events.

hammerTime.on('pinchin', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchin');

}).on('pinchout', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchout');

}).on('pinchend', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchend');
});
```

This works fine, I can detect the pinch, but now on my pinch target I can't zoom the browser any more? How can I use the pinch event and allow the default browser pinch zooming? I need to do some stuff on pinch but I still want people to be able to zoom in.

I'm using hammer.js 2.0.4 in case it matters.

Answer (score 6):

I was having a hard time with this too, until I came across the touch-action property. by setting it to auto, hammer stops blocking the events, and allows the browser to do it's own zoom.

```
var hammerTime = new Hammer($('#hammerTarget').get(0), {touchAction : 'auto'});

hammerTime.add(new Hammer.Pinch({event: 'pinch'})); // Add pinch gesture events.

hammerTime.on('pinchin', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchin');

}).on('pinchout', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchout');

}).on('pinchend', function(event) {
    console.log('hammer pinchend');
});
```

See the doc : http://hammerjs.github.io/touch-action/

Comment: The docs at the linked page say `Hammer would probably break. You have to call preventDefault manually to fix this. You should only use this if you know what you’re doing.`  And course I *don't* know what I'm doing, because I haven't been able to find anything that coherently and accurately describes exactly when and where I need to call preventDefault!