# How to keep default browser behavior (zoom) on pinch with Hammerjs?

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, pinchzoom

I use Hammerjs for swiping and tapping. However as soon as I start using it on any element

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("square"));
```

the default browser's behavior for "pinch" gestures (zooming in or out) stops working.

Since I don't need any custom handling for pinch, I tried to disable the event recognizer like this:

```
hammer.get("pinch").set({enable: false});
```

No luck. The following [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9g9fsky/38/) illustrates the problem.

How can I keep my "swipe" handlers and let the browser do its job on pinch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30452422/how-can-i-keep-the-browser-pinch-to-zoom-and-use-the-hammer-js-pinch-events?rq=1)

```
{touchAction : "auto"}
```

is the way to go. Here is the corrected [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p9g9fsky/40/).

Comment: this seems to horribly break everything else.  for instance, for pan events, a smooth pan gives 1-5 pan events before the pan terminates, even though it really hasn't!  I have seen various things about using preventDefault, some including nonsense events like "tap" on document, none of which have fixed the issue for me.